# Nginx on AWS EC2 connection rejected on non www request

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server

I have an AWS EC2 instance with 80 and 443 open for web access running Ubuntu, no UFW as the instance provides one. Lets say that the instance IP is 123.123.123.123.

In the instance I have Nginx with this simple configuration:

```
server {
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;
}
```

The domain `example.com` is mine and is correctly pointing to the instance, as well as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com):

```
$ dig +short example.com
123.123.123.123
$ dig +short www.example.com
123.123.123.123
```

When I request `www.example.com` I receive proper response:

```
$ curl www.example.com
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
etc.
```

But when  requesting `example.com` the connection is rejected:

```
$ curl example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Checking the logs of this server I see nothing when requesting `example.com`:

```
$ tail -f  /var/log/nginx/example.com.log
188.170.74.30 - admin [01/Feb/2022:17:10:58 +0000] "GET /favicons/android-icon-192x192.png HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://www.example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
188.170.74.30 - admin [01/Feb/2022:17:11:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
188.170.74.30 - admin [01/Feb/2022:17:11:12 +0000] "GET /main-e32c.css HTTP/1.1" 200 22171 "https://www.example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
188.170.74.30 - admin [01/Feb/2022:17:11:13 +0000] "GET /client-e32c.js HTTP/1.1" 200 975891 "https://www.example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"

etc.
```

Ufw is inactive, as AWS provides its own firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

If anyone has an an idea of what may be happening I would be grateful. At this point I don't know why this connection through port 80 is rejected without `www.`

---

Edit

There is something interesting here I just found with `nmap`.
Running `nmap` against port `80` on `www.example.com`:

```
$ nmap -p 80 www.example.com               
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-02-01 21:19 
Nmap scan report for www.example.com (123.123.123.123)
Host is up (0.072s latency).
rDNS record for 123.123.123.123: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxx-x.compute.amazonaws.com

PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.09 seconds
```

But when running it against same port on `example.com`:

```
$ nmap -p 80 example.com
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-02-01 21:19 
Nmap scan report for example.com (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

`127.0.0.1: localhost`? The request is going back to my computer? Lets check my hosts file…

```
$  sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

Of course, I added `example.com` to hosts file to be able to work on `dev.example.com`. Why I didn't add `dev.example.com` directly, I don't know, this was a mistake.

So this error I'm experiencing only happens from my development computer as the request is redirected to localhost due to my `hosts` file configuration.

Comment: It looks like `www.example.com` and `example.com` do not point to the same address.

Comment: But they do point to same IP, checked with `dig +short example.com`

Comment: @jordanm you were right, `example.com` was pointing to `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Me: Me, please check `hosts`file:

```
$  sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

Also me: oops!